# Why doesn’t my NSMutableArray subclass work as expected?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have subclassed NSMutableArray as follows:

Base Class:

```
@interface MyBaseMutableArray : NSMutableArray {
    // Database variables
    NSString * databaseName;
    NSString * databasePath;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * databasePath;

- (id)initWithContentsOfSQLiteDB:(NSString *)dbTable;
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void) readFromDatabase;

@end
```

Subclass:

```
@interface IngredientsMutableArray : MyBaseMutableArray
{

}

-(void) readFromDatabase;

@end
```

When I create an IngredientsMutableArray I do the following:

```
IngredientsMutableArray * i  = [[IngredientsMutableArray alloc]
    initWithContentsOfSQLiteDB:@"MyIngredientsDB.sql"];
```

BUT, when I try to perform the [self addObject:ingred] I throw an exception as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray count]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[IngredientsMutableArray count]!'
```

I believe I am not initializing the NSMutableArray correctly.  I was going to us initWithCapaciity, but I do not know the count before the SQL call.  I think I am overlooking something obvious, but being somewhat of a newbie to Objective C I am slightly befuddled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Very short answer: you can not, realistically, subclass NSMutableArray. Take another approach.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003688) you need to:

> Methods to Override
>
> NSMutableArray‘s methods are
>   conceptually based on these primitive
>   methods:
>
> ```
> insertObject:atIndex:
>
> removeObjectAtIndex:
>
> addObject:
>
> removeLastObject
>
> replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
> ```
>
> In a subclass, you must override all
>   these methods, although you can
>   implement the required functionality
>   using just the first two (however this
>   is likely to be inefficient). You must
>   also override the primitive methods of
>   the NSArray class.

But the *real* answer is that you don't really want to be subclass it. There are two options:

1. Use a category
2. Create a new class that has an `NSArray` as a member variable

I think I'd go for option two in this case.

In general, you tend to subclass system classes much less often than you would in C# or Java.

Comment: I did think of option 2 also.  So basically I was thinking I would create an object that maintains the list and any supporting functionality.  Does that make sense?  Is that where you were going?

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to subclass NSArray or NSMutableArray. It's a class cluster. From the [NSArray docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> Any subclass of NSArray must override
>   the primitive instance methods count
>   and objectAtIndex:. These methods must
>   operate on the backing store that you
>   provide for the elements of the
>   collection. For this backing store you
>   can use a static array, a standard
>   NSArray object, or some other data
>   type or mechanism. You may also choose
>   to override, partially or fully, any
>   other NSArray method for which you
>   want to provide an alternative
>   implementation.

As recommended in those same docs, try a category or composition, rather than inheritance.

Comment: Yes, I read about that, but I am confused.  Basically I have a collection of objects and was attempting to have the list class maintain itself and manage its own objects.  I guess I should re-think this, but I am not sure of alternatives.  In my c++ past this seemed to be a viable method.  Would it be better to have an object that would wrap the NSMutableArray and any supporting functions?

Comment: Certainly. You should generally favour composition before inheritance unless you have good reasons to do otherwise. Your current problem shows why – subclassing makes your class too dependent on the super class and that makes the code fragile.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html) – the `NSMutableArray` class just defines the interface and when you instantiate it, you get an object of a different, private type back. This makes `NSMutableArray` and other class clusters hard to subclass, you’d be much better off with composition. Read this [Friday Q&A with Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html) if you are interested in the [gory] details.