# Implementing Custom NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I would like to create my own custom NSMutableArray of my custom objects:

```
    @interface Course : NSObject {
        NSString *className;
        NSString *classGrade;
        NSInteger creditHours;
    }
```

This class will store an array of courses :

```
    @interface AllCourses : NSObject : NSMutableArray{
        NSMutableArray *arrClasses;
    }
```

I would like "AllCourses" to inherit from NSMutableArray so i can use it like any other NSMutableArray Object and add\remove courses from it and load it into a tableView etc...
So my question is ,if u would be so kind, is what my implementation of "AllCourses" should look like ?

Comment: Why do you need to subclass `NSMutableArray`? It does not look like correct practice.

Comment: How would correct practice look like ?

Comment: Depends on what you would like to achieve. Why won't you have standard `NSMutableArray` instead?

Comment: I am assuming the OP wants to achieve something like type-safety from that collection class. Still @Krizz is right, it is definitely not a good idea to subclass any iOS SDK collection class as those are actually class-clusters.

Comment: Whats wrong with sub-classing ? isnt that what OOP is all about ?

Comment: OOP is about subclassing, but not *all about*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all. If you want to extend a class you need to do this:

```
@interface YourCustomClass : SuperClass
```

In this manner `YourCustomClass` inherits properties and/or methods of your `SuperClass`.

About your question, Apple doc says in [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> There is typically little reason to subclass NSMutableArray. The class
>   does well what it is designed to do—maintain a mutable, ordered
>   collection of objects.

You could find the same suggestion in this stackoverflow topic: [should-i-subclass-the-nsmutablearray-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862619/should-i-subclass-the-nsmutablearray-class).

If you want to subclass `NSMutableArray` anyway, see the first link (NSMutableArray Class Reference). You must override 5 methods (see section Methods to Ovveride).

In my opinion you could just use `NSMutableArray` in the traditional way: create an `NSMutableArray` instance and add objects to it (here a simple example).

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
[myArray addObject:myNumber];
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

To override a method, in your .m file, you need to insert that method and add some logic within it. For example (it's only pseudo code here):

```
//.h

@interface YourClass: NSMutableArray

@end

//.m

@implementation YourClass

- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
   // your logic here
}

// do the same for other ones

@end
```

**BUT**, again, I suggest you to find a different way to do it because it's quite difficult (in this case) to extends a `NSMutableArray` class and obtain a fully functional class like the original one.

Alternative are:

1. Use Categories
2. Use composition (inside your class use a `NSMutableArray` instance variable)

Finally, I also suggest you to read the following discussion: [why-doesnt-my-nsmutablearray-subclass-work-as-expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937870/why-doesnt-my-nsmutablearray-subclass-work-as-expected). In particular, you have to note that

> In general, you tend to subclass system classes much less often than
>   you would in C# or Java.

as *Stephen Darlington* said.

Comment: How would i go about overidin those 5 methods ? i am actually looking for the code...

Comment: Thank you Flex for your thorough reply. Guess i will take everbody;s advice just use a local NSMutableArray and not a sub-class.

Comment: I _love_ how people say, "use categories", yet there is SO LITTLE information out there on how/why to _do that_, it makes me want to die.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there's no real use to subclassing that kind of stuff. You would be better off using a category. But, if you really insist on subclassing, here's how you should do this.

First of all, your interface declaration is wrong. Try it this way:

```
@interface AllCourses : NSMutableArray
@end
```

Also, you don't need to use a mutable array within your mutable array, all you gotta do is use self, like

```
[self addObject:<your object here>];
```

Comment: Thanks!, will that cover it ? and what is the full syntax for this overloading method ?

Comment: You want to overload addObject? I don't remember the whole syntax, but it's easy enough to find on developer.apple.com :)